# Porque no se me crea la tabla (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, table

Estoy realizando una pagina de consulta, la cual busca datos de una API, y los devuelve en la página. El tema es que no me estaria creando la tabla en el DOM. La consulta me trae los datos en formato JSON correcto. Pero la tabla no se me genera, les comparto el código que tengo para ver en que tengo el error. Gracias

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';


async function bionic_query(list, names_flag) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://splunk.hctint.com:9876/search", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://splunk.hctint.com',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ list, names_flag }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('data:', data); 
      return data;
    } else {
      console.log("Fetch did not succeed");
      return [];
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function handleQuery(query, isNames) {
    if (typeof query !== 'string' || query.length <= 0) {
      console.log("Empty query");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const responseData = await bionic_query([query], isNames);
      console.log('responseData: ', responseData)
      const noticiasData = JSON.parse(responseData.noticias)
      console.log("noticiasData: ", noticiasData);
      setData(noticiasData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  function handleButtonClick() {
    const query = document.getElementById('RUC').value;
    const isNames = document.getElementById('checked').checked;

    handleQuery(query, isNames);
  }

  function generateTable(){ 

    if (!data || data.length === 0){
      return null
    }

    const columnNames = Object.keys(data[0])
    return(
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {columnNames.map((columnName, index) => (
            <th key={index}>{columnName}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            {columnNames.map((columnName, index) => (
              <td key={index}>{item[columnName]}</td>
            ))}</tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
     </table>
     ) 
    
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Advantech Datos</h1>
      <p>Ingrese el RUC o Nombre de la persona a buscar</p>
      <input type="text" id="RUC" />
      <button id="buttonSearch" onClick={handleButtonClick}>
        Buscar
      </button>
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked id="checked" />
      {generateTable()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Cuando le doy a buscar el DOM, no me devuelve nada. Queda en blanco.
Intente de mil maneras solucionarlo pero no pude, en los console.log verifico que los datos traidos desde la API, son en formato JSON, por eso los parseo.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, en vez de usar `async function handleQuery` deberías usar `useEffect` y dentro del efecto ejecutar la funcion `async/await` y el `setState`